# Android - Fetching Data from URL issue

Tags: android

i am trying to fetching data from url, its showing null.

here is my code

```
                try {
                URL urlA = new URL("http://www.domain.com/work123.html");
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlA.openStream()));

                String inputLineA;

                while ((inputLineA = in.readLine()) != null)
                    htmlCodeA += inputLineA;

                in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e.toString());
                }
```

please let me know where i am doing mistake.

best regards,

Comment: catch exception without any error handler is not a good work , maybe you try connect internet in UI thread or you don't set permission , try post Exception error

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted in the Android section, it's almost guaranteed that you will want to run this in an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and not block the UIThread with that AsyncTask.

```
String htmlCodeA = "";
//
// A bunch of lines later...
try{
  HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://www.domain.com/work123.html");
  HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
  String line = "";
  while((line = reader.readLine())!=null)
  {
    htmlCodeA += line;
  }
}
catch(MalformedURLException e) { /* Do whatever you want here. */}
catch(IOException e) { /* Do whatever you want here. */}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
URL connectURL = new URL(urlstring);

        HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();
```

hc.setConnectTimeout(20 * 1000);

```
                Enumeration kyes = header.keys();
                while (kyes.hasMoreElements()) {
                    String key = (String) kyes.nextElement();
                    String value = (String) header.get(key);
                    hc.setRequestProperty(key, value);
                }
```

InputStream is = hc.getInputStream();

```
                resMessage = new String(readFully(is),  "UTF-8")


public static byte[] readFully(InputStream input) throws IOException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead;
    ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1)
    {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    return output.toByteArray();
}
```